# ExtJs Tabpanel Close Event with Closable tabs

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, tabpanel

The listener I set up with doesn't seem to trigger. Here is my code:

```
  new Ext.TabPanel({
        id:'content-tab-panel',
        renderTo: 'trx_tabs_ext',
        activeTab: 0,
        minTabWidth: 150,
        tabWidth:180,
        enableTabScroll: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        resizeTabs:true,
        defaults: {
            autoScroll:true
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'No Active Chat',
            id: 'no_chat',
            closable: true,
            autoScroll: false,
            margins: '0 0 0 0',
            html: "<div id=\"chat_window_viewer\"  style=\"width:900px;height:440px;text-align:left; \">&nbsp;</div>"
        }],
        width: '100%',
        height: '400px',
        listeners: {
            tabchange: function(tabPanel, newTab, oldTab, index)
            {
                console.log('change tab');
            },
            beforeadd : function (tabpane, component, index) {
                console.log('Adding new tab');
            },
            beforeclose: function(element) {
                console.log('closing');
            }
        }
    });
```

The beforeadd an tabchange triggers and do so by writing a log at the console. But, the beforeclose does not.

I also tried putting it inside the item of the Tabpanel, does not work either.

What is the correct way to adding a close event in the TabPanel?

Comment: the `tabpanel` component doesnt have a `beforeclose` event unless it is `closable: true`. you might want to try `beforeremove`. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To get items close event, add listener to that item.

Fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/59f

Answer (score 0):

Which version of library you are using? Note that beforclose event available since 2.3.0.

It works for me when i listening event for item, not for whole panel

```
new Ext.TabPanel({
        id:'content-tab-panel',
        renderTo: 'trx_tabs_ext',
        activeTab: 0,
        minTabWidth: 150,
        tabWidth:180,
        enableTabScroll: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        resizeTabs:true,
        defaults: {
            autoScroll:true
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'No Active Chat',
            id: 'no_chat',
            closable: true,
            autoScroll: false,
            margins: '0 0 0 0',
            html: "<div id=\"chat_window_viewer\"  style=\"width:900px;height:440px;text-align:left; \">&nbsp;</div>",
            listeners:{
                'beforeclose': function(){console.log('closed')}
            }
        }],
        width: '100%',
        height: '400px',
        listeners: {
            tabchange: function(tabPanel, newTab, oldTab, index)
            {
                console.log('change tab');
            },
            beforeadd : function (tabpane, component, index) {
                console.log('Adding new tab');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Its Extjs 2.2. Yes, its a dinosaur. I've been meaning to upgrade but have no time. And you have no parameter for the listener in the item? it works?

Comment: I'm afraid beforeclose event available since 2.3.0.  

ExtJS is javascript framework, therefore it follows javascript rules. If you do not need parameters - don't send it.

Comment: *mario died music* That's it, its time for an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Extjs 2.3.0**, `tabpanel`s have a `beforeclose` event:

> **beforeremove**( this, component, eOpts )
>
> Fires before any `Ext.Component` is removed from the container. A handler can return false to cancel
>   the remove.
>
> Available since: 2.3.0
>
> Parameters
>
> - this : `Ext.container.Container`
> - component : `Ext.Component`
>     The component being removed
> - eOpts : `Object` The options object passed
>     to `Ext.util.Observable.addListener`.

so just add a listener in your `tabpanel`:

```
listeners: {

    beforeremove: function (panel, item, eOpts) {
        console.log(item); // the tab to be removed
    }
 . . . . 
}
```